# How to generate the regex for my pattern below?

Tags: regex

I have been very headache on questions like regex.

I have a text file with the following pattern:

> $~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx
>   $~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$

You can see the $~$ is the padding for the n fields, ending with $~$, field delimiter is |, some fields are null ($~$$~$), otherwise xxxx is the field's content.

I tried to build a regex to match this pattern but stuck at the very first field:

```
^\$~\$[a-z|A-Z|_]+\$~\$\|
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

In the data to be processed, there should be exactly 17 fields, and each field is surrounded by $~$, with delimiter as |, in some rare cases, the data is wrong and I need to grep out the mal-formed lines. Can you further enlighten how do I do that? Thanks.

UPDATE2:

Thanks to @Curious_Mind for https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/13, almost there but when I check it against:

```
$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$

$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$||$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$xxxx$~$||$~$$~$
```

The second line is indeed a malformed line: there are occurences of "||", the pattern should strictly matching:
1. 17 fields padding with pairs of $~$
2. all fields are delimited by "|"

All unmatched lines would be excluded by the regex, later on I will use this regex in Unix to grep out the data.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is your expected output? the `xxxx`'s from the string?

Comment: Expected output is all lines matching the pattern, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the initial `^` caret character and wrap your matches in parenthesis `()` so you can get the string easily. Let's try like this way-

```
\$~\$([a-z|A-Z|_]+)\$~\$\|
```

**REGEX:** https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/11

**EDIT:** AS per OP comment, I guess you can make both group `([a-z|A-Z|_]+)` and pipe `|` optional using `?` after that.

Comment: In the data to be processed, there should be exactly 17 fields, and each field is surrounded by $~$, with delimiter as |, in some rare cases, the data is wrong and I need to grep out the mal-formed lines. Can you further enlighten how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: yes, except the last field is missing, your regex got 16, need to include the last one

Comment: Thanks, yah, I got that as well, however, I just tested with another line and realized this is not doing what I need, updated in the OP.

Comment: @mdivk I've **Edited** my answer also. Best of luck :) Have a good day mate

Comment: Thank you @Curious_Mind, you too